# How to align parent component elements with child component elements using bootstrap, razor reusable components and styling?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, blazor-server-side, razor-components

Just learning Blazor and razor pages. I am using bootstrap to style my pages.
I would like to know how to handle this situation:

Parent references a child component. The Child component uses a label and a select list box.
Using bootstrap I style the component like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="@selectID" class="col-1 my-auto">Select a City:</label>
    <select ID="@selectID" class="form-control col-3" @onchange="OnSelectedCityChanged">
        @if (@CityList != null)
        {
            @foreach (var city in CityList)
            {
                <option value="@city">@city</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

This aligns the elements in the Child component nicely. However, in the parent, if I add anything inline behind the child conponent, the child component's styling is trashed. What if I want to add a message inline with the components. Can that be done? How can I do that? Here are some screen shots.
[image]

And here is an attempt to add the 'Message' inline with the component:
Parent's HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <Cities @bind-SelectedCity="city" selectID="selCities" CityList=@cities></Cities>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">Message</div>
</div>
```

And the image of the result:
[image]

So it appears the Child component is taking up the entire line and getting squished when bootstrap grid is used in the parent. What can I do to fix this? I really do not want my reusable code to take up the entire line. I'm sure it's my lack of experience, but that's why I'm asking for help.

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Boottrap 4.0 and above, probably this is what you are looking for ([working representation](https://jsfiddle.net/kpghde4w/)).

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="d-inline-flex">
      <label for="@selectID">Select a City:</label>
      <select ID="@selectID" class="form-control">
        @if (@CityList != null)
        {
            @foreach (var city in CityList)
            {
                <option value="@city">@city</option>
            }
        }
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>Message</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Suprabhat,

Thank you for taking time to consider this. Your 'working representation' is somewhat close to what I am trying to avoid. Though it does give me something to look further into. I'm going to mark your answer as the 'answer' for the points. In all the time this question has been up here, you are the only one who tried to help.

Thank You!